# Unable preview data for Flat files in Jboss developer studio

Tags: jboss-developer-studio, redhat-datavirt

I just installed JBoss developer studio  devstudio-11.2.0.GA-installer-standalone.jar on my Mac. When I am trying preview data for a local flat file, I am getting a following error.

> org.teiid.runtime.client.TeiidClientException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Remote
>   org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 SourceFile: File
>   not found marketdata-price.txt

I have JBoss Data Virtualization running on remote server. Could you please anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Regards,

Manikanth

Answer (score 0):

If you are running remote server the file should be reachable from the remote server. i.e. it needs to be on shared driver